# How to add navgrid options to a modal form?

Tags: jqgrid

I have to display an add modal form when the page loads.  I do so thusly:

```
$('#lst_totals').jqGrid('editGridRow','new');
```

Problem is, I don't know how to set the navgrid when I call it in this way.  I set the options on the add modal form in the navgrid like this:

```
// add options
   {    bSubmit: "Add",
        width: 350,
        recreateForm: true,
        recreateFilter: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        editData: { action:'grdTotals' },
   },
```

But these properties are not set for the add modal form I called when the page loads.  They only apply to add modal forms that are shown when the add button is clicked.  How do I apply options to modal forms that are called from outside of the jqGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.  It's as simple as I knew it would be:

```
$('#lst_totals').jqGrid('editGridRow','new',
    {   bSubmit: "Add",
        width: 350,
        recreateForm: true,
        recreateFilter: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,                
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        editData: { action:'grdTotals' },
    }
);
```

Basically, since I'm creating a new modal form that's not really part of the navgrid, I have to give it the properties I want it to have.  Above, the 'editGridRow' accepts a third parameter {} which can contain these properties.